# Pocketsphinx performance difference Java/Python

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to implement a simple voice recognition using pocketsphinx.
My aim is to listen continuously and react in case a certain keyword get transcribed from pocketsphinx.

So far this works like a charm, but I noticed a big difference using python or java.

The java implementation is taking nearly twice as long as the python implementation. 
(Around 3 seconds for java against <1.5 seconds for python)

Consider I am not taking into account initializing the decoder itself.

**Update - changed source code to actual used example**

**Java:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.*;

import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Decoder;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Config;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Segment;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SegmentIterator;

public class DecoderTest {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Config c = Decoder.defaultConfig();
        c.setString("-hmm", "../../model/en-us/en-us");
        c.setString("-lm", "../../model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
        c.setString("-dict", "../../model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        Decoder d = new Decoder(c);

        FileInputStream ais = new FileInputStream(new File("../../test/data/goforward.raw"));

        //Start Time measurement here
        d.startUtt();
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        d.setRawdataSize(300000);
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int nbytes;
        while ((nbytes = ais.read(b)) >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b, 0, nbytes);
            short[] s = new short[nbytes/2];
            bb.asShortBuffer().get(s);
            d.processRaw(s, nbytes/2, false, false);
        }
        d.endUtt();
        Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Long duration = end-start;
        System.out.println("Decoding took "+duration.toString()+"ms");
    }
}
```

**Python:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from os import environ, path
from timeit import default_timer as timer


from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "../../../model"
DATADIR = "../../../test/data"

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))

# Decode streaming data.
decoder = Decoder(config)

#Start Time measurement here
decoder.start_utt()
start = timer()
stream = open(path.join(DATADIR, 'goforward.raw'), 'rb')
while True:
  buf = stream.read(1024)
  if buf:
    decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
  else:
    break
decoder.end_utt()
end = timer()
print("Decoding took "+end-start+" ms")
```

**Setup:**

Raspberry Pi 3 with most recent raspian

- java version "1.8.0_65"

  - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
  - Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
- Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26) with [GCC 4.9.2] on linux2

**Question is, am I missing something here or is python really that faster than java?**

Comment: It is ok to see some performance difference, but to understand them you need to provide more information. It is not quite clear what exactly do you run and what do you measure. What exactly takes 3 seconds? The code you provided does different things.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll add a more specific example soon.